# Probability distribution of minimum statistic

Tags: probability-distributions, order-statistics

There are two random variables: $X$ and $Y$, which are independent.  $X$ is drawn from a continuous cdf $G(x)$ with support $[a,b)$ and $Y$ is drawn from a cdf that consists of continuous part $F(y)$ with support $[a,b)$ and atom $k$ at $b$. $G$ and $F$ are not the same.

I wish to find the distribution of minimum of these two random variables.

Attempt: I guess a starting point is $\Pr[min(X,Y)\leq z] =  1 - \Pr[X\geq z] \Pr[Y\geq z]$.  But I dont know how to continue further

Comment: I assume X and Y are independant ? Have you informations about Pr[X≥z] and Pr[Y≥z] ? (wouldn't they be uniform on [a,b) for instance, plus the atom mass in b for Y ?)

Comment: You speak of an atom $k(y)$ at $b$. Isn't it just a constant $k=1-P(Y<b)>0$? I don't see how it can somehow depend on $y$.

Comment: @Evargalo They are independent.  I wish to solve the general case, but hints with uniform distribution will be helpful too

Comment: On RHS $\geq$ must be interchanged with $>$. It can be written as $1-(1-F(z))(1-G(z))$ and is the CDF of $\min(X,Y)$. Here I think of $G$ purely as the CDF of $Y$ being continuous on $\mathbb R-\{b\}$. Did you have something else in mind for $G$? Such as the CDF of $Y$ under the extra condition that $Y<b$. I wonder about that because you are saying that $G$ is continuous.

Comment: @drhab $G$ is cdf of $X$ not $Y$, and $G$ and $F$ do not need to be necessarily the same

Comment: Sorry, I switched. It is evident that they are not the same if $k>0$. One of them is continuous and the other is not.

Comment: @drhab What do you think of this: Since $Y$ is equal to $b$ with probability $k$, we have $\Pr[min(X,Y)\leq z] = k G(z) + (1-k)(1 - \Pr[X>z]\Pr[Y>z])$?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an answer to a comment, but is too big for a comment.

For $z\geq b$ it is evident that $P(\min(X,Y)\leq z)=1$, and letting $z<b$ we have: $$\Pr(\min(X,Y)\leq z)=$$$$\Pr(\min(X,Y)\leq z\mid Y=b)\Pr(Y=b)+\Pr(\min(X,Y)\leq z\mid Y<b)\Pr(Y<b)=$$$$\Pr(X\leq z)k+\Pr(\min(X,Y)\leq z\mid Y<b)(1-k)=$$$$G(z)k+[1-\Pr(\min(X,Y)>z\mid Y<b)](1-k)=$$$$G(z)k+[1-\Pr(X>z\mid Y<b)\Pr(Y>z\mid Y<b)](1-k)=$$$$G(z)k+[1-\Pr(X>z)\Pr(Y>z\mid Y<b)](1-k)$$

Now note that $\Pr(Y>z\mid Y<b)\Pr(Y<b)=\Pr(z<Y<b)$ leading to: $$\Pr(Y>z\mid Y<b)=\frac{\Pr(Y>z)-k}{1-k}\tag1$$

In your comment you take wrongly $\Pr(Y>z)$ in stead of the RHS of $(1)$.

Comment: thanks pal, indeed it should be that way!